# Hack const array size restriction

Tags: c++, arrays

The c++ standard doesn't support vsa(variable size arrays), but only for multidimensional arrays. Initializing a onedimensional array like this one works like a charm:

```
uint32_t width = 640; // some non-constant value
Object arrayOfObjects = new Object[width];
```

So technically it would be possible to write a wrapper object to bypass this restriction like this:

```
class 2DarrayWrapper{
public:
    2DarrayWrapper(uint32_t width, uint32_t height):theArray(new Object[width * height]), width(width), height(height) {};
    Object* theArray;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;

    inline Object* operator[](int index) {
        return &theArray[width*index];
    };
};

uint32_t width = 640;
uint32_t height = 400;

2DarrayWrapper wrapper = new 2DarrayWrapper(width, height);
wrapper[25][30] = 35;
delete wrapper;
```

What i want to know, what are the general disadvantages of this method? There are no constants given, so i could imagine a decrease in speed because the compiler can't optimize the memory access at this point.

Also, you could templatify this design, to make it more dynamical...

Comment: What's wrong/different with `std::vector<std::vector<Object>>`?

Comment: It is pretty standard to do this kind of thing. But one wouldn't then instantiate the wrapper with `new`. And one would respect the rule of three/five/zero.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's an array of arrays, not a multidimensional array, though you can easily use `std::vector<Object>` to implement a multidimensional array.

Comment: I thought of `std::vector` too, but i think it would be a more lightweight solution. Also it tempted me to be able to bypass restrictions

Comment: Implementing `std::vector` yourself isn't any more lightweight than using `std::vector`.

Comment: The overhead in vector is probably just one data member (vector needs to be able to give its size *and* capacity in constant time.) So if that is too much, you could consider implementing your own version of `std::dynarray`, and use that to implement the 2D array container.